# Proof derivative using Cauchy-Riemann

Tags: complex-analysis

Using the Cauchy–Riemann equations I have to prove that $f(z)=e^{iz}$ is analytic and its derivative is $ie^{iz}$

Using $z=x+iy$ this is what I have done:

$$e^{iz}=e^{i(x+iy)}=e^{ix-y}= \frac{e^{ix}}{e^{y}}=\frac{\cos x+i\sin x}{e^{y}}$$ so, $u(x,y) = \frac{\cos x}{e^y}$ and $v(x,y) = \frac{\sin x}{e^y}$

I've made all the derivatives and $u_x(x,y)=v_y(x,y)$ and $u_y(x,y)=-v_x(x,y)$

I've then made 
$$f'(z)=u_x(x,y)+iv_y(x,y)=\frac{-\sin x}{e^y}+\frac{i\cos x}{e^y} = \frac{-\sin x+i\cos x}{e^y}$$
but now i'm stuck. How can I go from here to $ie^{iz}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{-\sin x + i\cos x}{e^y} = e^{-y}(i(i\sin x+\cos x)) = i\left(e^{-y}e^{ix}\right) = i e^{i(x+iy)} = i e^{iz}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain better the part $(i(i\sin x+\cos x))$? I believe that you've multiplied $−sinx+icosx$ by $i$ but if you multiply don't you have to divide by $i$?

Comment: $-\sin x+i\cos x = i^2\sin x + i\cos x$.  Now there's a common factor that can be pulled out, getting $i(i\sin x+\cos x)$.

Comment: Thanks. Not in a million years I would figure that out. Many, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Good job!

Hint: $ie^{iz}=ie^{(x+yi)i}=ie^{ix-y}=e^{-y}(ie^{ix})$

Comment: Thanks. I've burned my head but I can't figure how to turn $\frac{-\sin x+i\cos x}{e^y}$ in $ie^{iz}$ :(